# Laravel migration, fails on hasColumn method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations, mysql-8.0

I am using laravel 5.2 version and PHP 7.1. I am trying to migrate the files from my laravel project where I have code to check column existence as shown below -

```
if (!Schema::hasColumn('table1', 'column1')) {
    // Add column1
}
```

I know the code is perfectly fine and this has already worked several times while setting up the same code. But now I am trying this on separate machine and fails with an error -

> [ErrorException]
>                              Undefined property:
>   stdClass::$column_name

I can get rid of this error if I remove the hasColumn checks from the code, but that's something I have written throughout the code and cannot modify each and every migration just for the sake of running migration.

Any help over this is much appreciated.

Stack trace:

> [ErrorException] 
> Undefined property: stdClass::$column_name
>
> Exception trace: () at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/MySqlProcessor.php:18
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/MySqlProcessor.php:18
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\MySqlProcessor->Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors{closure}()
>   at n/a:n/a array_map() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/MySqlProcessor.php:21
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\MySqlProcessor->processColumnListing()
>   at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/MySqlBuilder.php:40
>   Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder->getColumnListing() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php:69
>   Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder->hasColumn() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:217
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/database/migrations/2017_07_28_053158_add_columns_to_project_configurations_table.php:16
>   AddColumnsToProjectConfigurationsTable->{closure}() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php:69
>   Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint->__construct() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php:207
>   Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder->createBlueprint() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php:116
>   Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder->table() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:217
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/database/migrations/2017_07_28_053158_add_columns_to_project_configurations_table.php:103
>   AddColumnsToProjectConfigurationsTable->up() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:135
>   Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runUp() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:112
>   Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runMigrationList() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:85
>   Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->run() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:74
>   Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->fire() at
>   n/a:n/a call_user_func_array() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:507
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:150
>   Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:238
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:136
>   Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:840
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:190
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:114
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:107
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at
>   /private/var/www/html/whitelabel_eb/artisan:35

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace instead of just the immediate error?

Comment: The same thing was experienced in post [https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/1528](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/1528). But they have used voyager as `php artisan voyager:install --with-dummy`.

Comment: @JohnEllmore there is no stack trace, only the error shown above.

Comment: Unfortunately, the error message above isn't very much to go off of. Are you running these migrations via the artisan command line tool? If so, I think adding `-vvv` should includes a full stack trace with any errors. So that'd be `php artisan migrate -vvv`.

Comment: Hi @JohnEllmore, I have added the stack trace in below answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have did following changes to resolve this issue.
Goto following path: `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/MySqlProcessor.php`

Change this,
`return $r->column_name;`  line number 18 
  to
`return $r->COLUMN_NAME;`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the problem, probably https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/21037 this resolves it, but this change was made for Laravel 5.5. Laravel 5.2 isn't supported any more, so you could try to use your own fork with this fix when needed - you can use [Composer VCS](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository) feature for that.

Of course upgrading to latest versions might be a good idea (a lot of issues were solved in later releases) but assuming your app is complex and doesn't have decent tests it might be risky.

Comment: @DIGVJSS But as I said you can fork repo and add some change to your fork and use VCS to fix this single thing without updating your project to later Laravel versions